# Update Object on Array

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java, morphia, nosql

How can I update a specific object in an array?

For the structure bellow, using morphia, how can I update an Obj2 with a specific id?

```
@Entity("obj1")
public class Obj1 {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private List<Obj2> objs = new ArrayList<>();


    public Obj1() {
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Obj2> getObjs() {
        return objs;
    }

    public void setObjs(List<DataSource> objs) {
        this.objs = objs;
    }

}
```

Embedded Object

```
@Embedded
public class Obj2 {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;

    public Obj2() {
    }


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Embedded` classes don't get assigned an ID unless you do it manually.  Apart from that, you'll have to load the `Obj1` instance in your app, find the specific `Obj2` instance you're interested in, update that object in memory and save back the `Obj1` instance.